# R: Replacing values in range of columns with NA

Tags: r, subset, threshold

I have a data frame in R that is set up like this example:

| Samples | cor1 | pval1 | cor2 | pval2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | -1 | -1 | -.05 | 1.2 |
| EFG | -0.2 | -0.3 | 0.2 | 0.1 |
| HIJ | -0.3 | -0.1 | 0.8 | 0.9 |

Is there any way to replace the values that are less than/equal to a cutoff value  in specific columns (e.g. column pval1 and column pval2 in this case) with NA? I do not want to eliminate the rows altogether such it is a large dataset with many columns but I'd like to remove values in certain columns that are below a threshold.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `across` in `dplyr` -

```
library(dplyr)

cutoff <- 0.2
df <- df %>% mutate(across(starts_with('pval'), ~replace(., . <= cutoff, NA)))
df

#  Samples cor1 pval1 cor2 pval2
#1     ABC -1.0    NA  1.2   1.0
#2     EFG -0.2    NA  0.2    NA
#3     HIJ -0.3    NA  0.8   0.9
```

**data**

It is easier to help if you provide data in a [reproducible format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269) -

```
df <- structure(list(Samples = c("ABC", "EFG", "HIJ"), cor1 = c(-1, 
-0.2, -0.3), pval1 = c(-0.05, -0.3, -0.1), cor2 = c(1.2, 0.2, 
0.8), pval2 = c(1, 0.1, 0.9)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your you want to replace values less than or equals -0.2 in `pval1` column with NA.

```
 mydat
#  Samples cor1 pval1  cor2 pval2
#1     ABC -1.0  -1.0 -0.05   1.2
#2     EFG -0.2  -0.3  0.20   0.1
#3     HIJ -0.3  -0.1  0.80   0.9

cutoff = -0.2

mydat$pval1[mydat$pval1 <= cutoff] = NA

mydat
#  Samples cor1 pval1  cor2 pval2
#1     ABC -1.0    NA -0.05   1.2
#2     EFG -0.2    NA  0.20   0.1
#3     HIJ -0.3  -0.1  0.80   0.9
```

To do the replacement in many columns, you can use a function. Here is an example of a simple function to do that:

```
nafill = function(df, cutoff, col_names){

# Subset the original data frame with the targeted columns

df1 = df[,col_names]

#Apply the replacement with NA in all columns in the 2nd data frame.

df1[df1 <= cutoff] = NA

# Assign the resulted column in the 2nd data frame to the original data frame

df[,col_names] = df1[, col_names]

return(df)

}
```

Here is the application of the `nafill` function:

```
mydat2
#Samples cor1 pval1  cor2 pval2
#1     ABC -1.0  -1.0 -0.05   1.2
#2     EFG -0.2  -0.3  0.20  -0.3
#3     HIJ -0.3  -0.1  0.80   0.9

nafill(mydat2, -0.2, c('pval1', 'pval2'))

#  Samples cor1 pval1  cor2 pval2
#1     ABC -1.0    NA -0.05   1.2
#2     EFG -0.2    NA  0.20    NA
#3     HIJ -0.3  -0.1  0.80   0.9
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to do this for many columns at once (every other column)? I'm not sure if a for loop would be best here or if there is another way.

Comment: Yes, you can do that for many columns by using a function without for loop. Please check my edited answer.